# Поиск по фрейму данных

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, обработка-данных

У меня есть 2 фрейма данных.

Первый:

```
    word    probabilityham  probabilityspam

0   Subject       0.002401       0  
1   a             0.017705       0  
2   aa            0.000018       0  
3   aaa           0.000009       0  
4   aaai          0.000013       0
```

И второй:

```
    word    probabilityham  probabilityspam  
0   Subject        0               0.001728  
1   a              0               0.017424  
2   aa             0               0.000004  
3   aaa            0               0.000032  
4   aaarghh        0               0.000004
```

Мне нужно в первом фрейме найти такой же элемент из второго фрейма и вставить соответствующее ему значение `probabilityspam` в первый.

К примеру для первой строки должен быть такой результат `0 Subject 0.002401 0.001728`.

Я это попробовал сделать с помощью `iloc` и обычного поиска, но это работает медленно.

Есть ли способ реализовать быстрее?

Answer (score 3):

Если я Вас правильно понял, возможно пригодиться `dataframe.merge()`.
Удалите в одном data frame столбец с нулями, а дальше `df1.merge(df2)`.

Comment: так теряются значения, которых нет во втором dataframe (в `'aaai'` строчке) с `merge()` придётся все столбцы дублирующие убирать: `df1.drop(columns='probabilityspam').merge(df2.drop(columns='probabilityham'), how='left', on='word')`

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [54]: d1['probabilityspam'] = d1['word'].map(d2.set_index('word')['probabilityspam'])

In [55]: d1
Out[55]:
      word  probabilityham  probabilityspam
0  Subject        0.002401         0.001728
1        a        0.017705         0.017424
2       aa        0.000018         0.000004
3      aaa        0.000009         0.000032
4     aaai        0.000013              NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы присвоить значения `probabilityspam` столбца из второго dataframe в первый в строчках с одинаковыми `word` значениями:

```
ind = df1.word == df2.word, 'probabilityspam'
df1.loc[ind] = df2.loc[ind]
```

Это требует, чтобы одинаковые значения на одних и тех же строчках шли как в примере в вопросе, иначе можно отсортировать:

```
df.sort_values(by='word', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```